# AngularJS - Firebase resetPassword changes not getting reflected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Please see below HTML/Javascript: After entering incorrect email address and then submitting the form, the error message is not shown to the user, however, if we try to append additional characters to the exiting entries then the message appears on screen. In debug, the variable $scope.fError is true and $scope.fErrorMessage has the correct text, however, as mentioned abvoe, it is not getting displayed on screen.

```js
.controller('PasswordCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'CommonProp', function ($scope, $location, CommonProp) {
        $scope.forgotpassword = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var firebaseObj = new Firebase(CommonProp.getFirebaseURL());
            login.loading = true;
            if ($scope.passwordForm.$valid) {
                firebaseObj.resetPassword({
                    email: $scope.user.emailaddress
                }, function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        $scope.fError = true;
                        if (error.code == "INVALID_USER") {
                            $scope.fErrorMessage = "The specified user account does not exist.";
                        } else {
                            $scope.fErrorMessage = "Error resetting password:";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $scope.fErrorMessage = "Password reset email sent successfully!";
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    var login = {};
    $scope.login = login;

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>AngularJS & Firebase Web App</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="forgotpassword/forgotpassword.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PasswordCtrl">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="padding-bottom:0">
            <h2>Password reset.</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="form-signin" name="passwordForm">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : passwordForm.emailaddress.$invalid }">
                <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" ng-model="user.emailaddress">
                <p ng-show="passwordForm.emailaddress.$invalid">Enter a valid email.</p>
                <p style="color: red;" ng-show="fError">{{fErrorMessage}}</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" ladda-loading="login.loading" data-style="expand-right" ng-click="forgotpassword($event);" ng-disabled="!user.emailaddress" class="btn btn-lg segoe-ui-light ladda-button btn-primary btn-block"><span class="ladda-label">Reset</span></button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to wrap assigning of $scope.fError = true; in $scope.$apply. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: Thank you. like this?                                                                                       if ($scope.passwordForm.$valid) {
                firebaseObj.resetPassword({
                    email: $scope.user.emailaddress
                }, function (error) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        if (error) {
                            $scope.fError = true;
                            if (error.code == "INVALID_USER") {
                                $scope.fErrorMessage = "The specified user account

Comment: It is working after using $scope.apply in above manner.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reset of the password happens asynchronously (since it is done on the Firebase servers). Once the operation is complete, your callback function is called. But at that point, AngularJS is not aware of any changes you make to the `$scope` anymore. The solution is (as @OleksandrPapchenko mentioned in his comment) to tell AngularJS about the change, by calling `$apply()` or by making it inside a `$timeout` call:

```
firebaseObj.resetPassword({
    email: $scope.user.emailaddress
}, function(error) {
    $timeout(function() {
        if (error) {            
            $scope.fError = true;
            if (error.code == "INVALID_USER") {
                $scope.fErrorMessage = "The specified user account does not exist.";
            } else {
                $scope.fErrorMessage = "Error resetting password:";
            }
        } else {
            $scope.fErrorMessage = "Password reset email sent successfully!";
        }
    });
});
```

This ensures that AngularJS "sees" the change that was made to the `$scope` and updates the UI in its next update cycle.

Note that Firebase has created a binding library for AngularJS called [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/), which takes care of this type of plumbing for you. You might want to consider using that.

Comment: Thank you Frank. However, I have added reference to AngularFireJS (3rd from last). Please see the HTML. Further, the timeout example is still not working - I copied the entire block as it is. Any idea?